# A Banach predual of the space of measures absolutely continuous with respect to a given measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, duality-theorems

Let $(X, \mu)$ be a space with measure. [It is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Dual_spaces) that a Banach predual of the space of *finitely additive* measures that are absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ is $L^\infty (X, \mu)$.

If I strengthen the additivity requirement, is a Banach predual of the space of *countably additive* measures (i.e. measures in the usual sense) that are absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for a predual of $L^1(X,\mu)$, which by Radon-Nikodym corresponds to the absolutely continuous countably additive measures (in the $\sigma$-finite case).

In the case of counting measure on $\mathbb N$, $L^1(X,\mu)$ is
the sequence space $\ell^1$, and a predual of this is $c_0$.

In the case of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, there is no predual: see [this question and its answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137677/what-is-the-predual-of-l1)

Comment: Is it possible to recognize the spaces $X$ for which $L^1(X)$ does admit a Banach predual?