# Generalisation: isomorphism of sequences spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, isometry

As is well known, the isometric isomorphism $(c_0)^* \cong \ell^1$ holds.

Is there an analogous statement for general $L^p$ spaces?

Perhaps a good start would be to wonder about generalizations of sequence spaces like $c_0, c_{00}, c, \dots$. Is is sensible to think of those as special cases of functions converging to $0$ and functions with compact support?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Dual_spaces Maybe you are looking for that.

Comment: https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/4-06-dual-lp.pdf

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what I'm looking for. Isometries for dual spaces of $L^p$ spaces are generally well known (possibly what I'm asking for is so as well - we have not covered it in the lecture, though and I have not yet found anything on the internet/in literature) - what I ask in my question is different.

Comment: You may find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137677/what-is-the-predual-of-l1) interesting.

Comment: That's perfect - thank you.