# $f_n\xrightarrow{wk\star}f$ then $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f_n g \to \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f g$?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I know that if $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$
functions than if $f_n\xrightarrow{wk}f$ (weak convergence), we also have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f_n g \to \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f g$. But is the same true for weak-$\star$ convergence? If $f_n\xrightarrow{wk\star}f$ then $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f_n g \to \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f g$? (here $1/p+1/q=1$).

Comment: Where is $g$? Is it in $L^q$ where $q$ is the conjugate of $p$? Is $p>1$ or $p \geq 1$?

Comment: thank you, I edited. I guess I am interested in what would happen if $p>1$ as well as $p=1$ and maybe even $p=\infty$

Comment: For $1 <p <\infty$, this follows from the reflexivity of $L^p$ spaces, which implies weak and weak star convergence are equivalent. This is not true in $L^\infty
$.

Answer (score 2):

**Note** When $p >1$ then $L^p$ is a reflexive Banach space, and therefore the weak and weak-* topologies coincide.

For $p=1$, $L^1$ is not the dual of anything, see for example the link @rubikscube09 suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137677/what-is-the-predual-of-l1) or [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243715/is-the-l1-space-dual-to-a-banach-space) MO post. This means we cannot talk about the weak* topology on $L^1$.

Comment: To see why $L^1$ has no predual, the following answer is helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137677/what-is-the-predual-of-l1

Comment: @rubikscube09 Thank you, I realised that my argument was not true.

Comment: Tank you. Is the result still true for $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^d})$? Why? (the space is not reflexive this time)

Comment: @roi_saumon I think no for the following reason. The unit ball is weak* compact, but it is not weak compact (as weak compactness of the unit ball is equivalent to reflexivity). Moreover, the weak topology on the unit ball $B$ is metrisable by Eberlein-Smulain theorem. Finally, the weak* topology is metrisable on $B$ since $L^1$ is separable.

Comment: ... This implies that there exists a sequence $f_n$ in the unit ball which is weak* convergent but not weak convergent. This sequence converges in the weak* topology but I think doesn't satisfy the given relation (not sure)